# Ubuntu Crashed At Login Screen

Tags: login, crash

When I start my laptop, Ubuntu loads normally, but when I get to the login screen for my account my mouse icon disappears and my trackpad and keyboard are not responding.

I have just installed Ubuntu 7 hours ago and I have steam and some games already installed so I am not re-installing the system unless there is no possible fix without re-installing it.

Thanks, Jonathan.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?